# Wordpress functions are not working inside iframe in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, iframe

I am using an iframe in wordpress, but the page inside iframe not supporting wordpress functions.
the page inside iframe is from the same domain.

**Here is what i am trying to do:**
 I am trying to call a css inside iframe page via wordpress function. Below is how i am using iframe tag :

```
<iframe id="iframeBox" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/iframe/scoreboard_summary.php" sandbox="" FRAMEBORDER="no" ></iframe>
```

Here is the css calling tag in my page **scoreboard_summary.php** :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/style.css">
```

the function get_template_directory_uri() is not working ?

Please let me know what should i need to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean that you are trying to "call a css?"

Comment: Wordpress version is 3.8.1

Comment: I am linking css to the page that i am using inside iframe, for that i am using wordpress function to link path of that css..

Answer (score 0):

iframes are just webpages pulled in and shown in a div. You can't interact with them in that way. PHP has already spit out what was defined by the loops and rules you set. You would want to look into ajax for something like that if you want to talk to the server and bring up new data at an interval, and skip the iframe.

`<?php echo 'do this thing' ?>` just turns into `this thing` after the page is loaded. There isn't much to hook into.

If you are just trying to get the stylesheet and apply it to you your page, then I would suggest getting the whole, standard, URL for that stylesheet and skip the template directory uri etc.

Maybe you can explain it better with some code or an example like this one, it's an iframe that refreshes at an interval. Good Luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/3C9qP/

Comment: Thanks sheriffderek, If i use whole, standard, URL for that stylesheet, it works fine but my question is that what should i need to do to work with wordpress functions inside iframe page?

Comment: The pages are each their own pages. You link their stylesheets to each of them in the head section of the html, - or in wordpress... a function places it there for you. Then you show one of the pages, in a div on the other. I don't know what you could get out of trying to connect the 2. Maybe I don't understand what your goal is?

Comment: Yes i can use ajax calls as an option for that, but i am getting scoreboard from that page so i need to refresh that every 60 second, so i think ajax calls would not be the best option for it.

Comment: So, if you are getting the page every 60 seconds, (which ajax is perfect for - but that doesn't matter right now) ---- what does grabbing stylesheets from one another have to do with anything? they are on the same site/domain - and already have style sheets, right?

Comment: If it works by itself - in the browser, it's going to function the same in an iframe.

Comment: My goal is to use wordpress functions inside iframe page, please help me to do that.

Comment: You can't. PHP is a server side language. It has a set of rules and then it spits out html from the rules - styles - database data etc. Then it's just there. That's all. If you want to talk to the server and have it spit out new stuff - that's a different thing - and cannot be done in your iframe. That is just a previously created webpage in a little box.

Comment: Thank you sheriffderek for your help, I will do some alternative for that.