# Call Wordpress function inside the source page of an iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I'm working on a theme for a Wordpress website. In a specific page template, I have to use an iframe to contain a page located in my theme's directory. I cannot use the html code without the iframe for other reasons (it's a revealjs presentation, which takes over the whole screen if not in an iframe).

The final page will only be visible to logged-in users. This is easy to achieve in the template itself, but for some reason I can't protect the source page of the iframe itself. Calling WP functions inside the source page - such as `is_user_logged_in()` - throws a `Call to undefined function error`.

Say `my-template.php` contains this html:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/subdirectory/my-source-page.php">
```

And `my-source-page.php` would be:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Some content.
    </body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

How can I call a Wordpress function from `my-source-page.php` ?

EDIT
[Apparently](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245364/how-can-i-call-wordpress-core-functions-in-external-scripts) I would need to require the `wp-load.php` script to be able to access WP functions. So that would be a different question.

Comment: To be specific, are you trying to use WP functions inside the iframe?

Comment: Exactly. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Ok, I think it's not possible. Maybe this can be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432953/wordpress-functions-are-not-working-inside-iframe-in-wordpress

Comment: It's strange because php code executes fine in `my-source-page.php`. It's only WP functions I don't have access to.

Comment: There is nothing strange about that. You can use PHP functions, because it is a PHP file.  But you can not use WP functions, if WP is not involved with this script so far _at all_ - and if this is a “stand-alone” script, then it simply isn’t. You can try and include the `wp-load.php` script - that should provide the base WP functionality. (To a certain degree; expecting all plugins etc. to work, or even client-side functionality, would be a bit much. If you needed _that_, then this should be integrated properly via the WP templating system to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the helpful comments, and to [these](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245364/how-can-i-call-wordpress-core-functions-in-external-scripts) [threads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26254/how-to-include-wp-load-php-from-any-location), I found a solution to my problem.

`my-source-page.php` now looks like this :

```
<?php 
// First we get the home path where WP lives
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/','',__DIR__);

// Then we load WP's core functionalities
require_once( $path . '/wp-load.php');

// And we can now use WP's core functions.
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Some content.
    </body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```